# Why exactly do some Decision Tree Algorithms sort the features before finding the best split?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, time-complexity

I read about the time complexity of Decision Tree Algorithms like CART, and understand why the time complexity, with sorting, can be approximated as $O(m n^2 \log n)$.

I will try to go through the calculation by my own words, which might help down the road of answering my main question.

Sorting $n$ elements, in general takes $O(n\log{n})$, assume we have $m$ features in our dataset, overall sorting at the root node takes $O(m n\log{n})$. The depth of a balanced binary tree can be computed as $\log n$, which gives us $2^{\log{n}}=n$ leaf nodes, where no further splitting is done. Since we have overall $2n -1$ nodes, we have $2n-1-n=n-1$ nodes where actually look for the best split. This leads overall to $O(m n^2 \log n)$. Let me know, if I am mistaken here already.

But, why exactly do we sort in the first place? We have to consider every feature and the corresponding unique values anyways, to find the maximum gain. I found a source that argued:

"It can be shown that optimal binary split on continuous features
is on the boundary between adjacent examples with different class labels
. This means that sorting the values of continuous features helps with determining a decision threshold
efficiently" (https://sebastianraschka.com/pdf/lecture-notes/stat451fs20/06-trees__notes.pdf).

However, I cannot figure out why this lets us determine the threshold more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithms needs to sort to do it efficiently. The decision tree is trying to find a threshold $\tau$ for a specific feature to split the samples into two nodes. When you have $n$ different values for a given feature, e.g. $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$, the best way to find a threshold is sorting these values, and trying each boundary (that is the mid-point between the two adjacent samples). There are theoretically $n-1$ different boundaries to try, but w/o sorting the features, you won't be able to see efficiently which boundary values you need to try.

Comment: The point being that the splits are determined based on the mid-point between the two closest points, that's why there are n-1 possible splits and why sorting is a good idea.

Comment: splitting on mid points only holds for continuous values though, right? Why would we split on mid points of categorical features?

Comment: @kklaw Categorical variables are transformed before training, usually into dummy variables - 0 and 1's. In that case the mid-point is 0.5, which then either includes or excludes this class.

Comment: What if there are more than 2 categorical variables? like color: red, green, blue? We can also easily include or exclude a class without the mid point, can't we? Moreover, we will never encounter values like $0.7$ in one of our categorical features, where the mid point would help, since we transform them to numerical values explicitly.

Comment: With the dummy variables, it's either that specific class or not. So, even in multi-class case, the split will ask if the samples are Class X or not, and split accordingly. There are some other DT algorithms (e.g. ID3) that deal with multiple classes differently, but that's not how CART works.

Comment: @gunes some implementations handle categorical features by making bipartitions of the categories, sometimes using mean responses to reduce the number of candidates: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/52103/55122  According to this answer, that was already part of the original CART paper: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/64760/55122

Comment: I have read your answer and I'm not sure I fully understand. Since we are trying every value of an individual feature in the dataset can't we just run a for loop over the different feature values ($x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots , x_n$) and use the comparison operator: $x_i \le threshold$ in unsorted order? So instead of using the threshold as a boundary we can use it as an exact feature value? Would we need to sort the feature values because it would be a lot more efficient with the comparison operation? For example, the different sorting algorithms used (timsort, quicksort, mergesort, etc.) it would

Comment: The thing is, how are you going to find the number of values that are smaller than an exact value, say $x_3$? Another for loop?